# nbconvert failed: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'enable_async'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I am trying to convert my Jupyter ipynb notebook to any other format. I am getting this error. Can anyone please help me with this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xtlf.png)

```
nbconvert failed: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'enable_async'
```

I have upgraded the jupyter also and updated the pandoc too. But still getting the same error.